# jQuery.on("click") does not work in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an AngularJs directive like this:

```
app.directive("showSuccess", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (_scope, _element) {
                _scope.$watch("successMessage", function (newVal) {
                    if (newVal) {
                        $(_element).find("#successMessage").html(newVal);
                        $(_element).slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
                    }
                });

                // Below code does not work
                $(_element).find(".hide-message").on("click", function () {
                    $(_element).slideUp();
                    _scope.successMessage = "";
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

The related HTML is:

```
<div class="ui-state-success" show-success>
    <i class="icon-ok-sign small"></i>
    <span id="successMessage"></span>
    <i class="icon-remove hide-message"></i>
</div>
```

When the panel is triggered to slide down, the screen shot is:
[image]

The problem is, when I click the "×", the panel won't slide up (although that it will slide up anyway after 3s delay).

I know I can do this using `ng-click`. But anyone knows why it does not work in this case? Thanks.

Comment: apply an `ng-click` to your element instead of using jquery

Comment: @Ronnie, yes, I know I can do that in that way. But do you have any idea what the problem is in this case? Thanks.

Comment: is `$(_element).find(".hide-message")` resolving? Can you console.log() the element you're trying to select and verify it is the right dom element? Even just a console.log() in the click function to see if it is even being called

Comment: @Ronnie Thanks Ronnie. Stryner has the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because jQuery animations are *queued*. You're calling `.slideUp()` on it and expecting it to slide instantly; however, it is currently waiting out it's 3 second delay.

One solution is to use [`.stop(true, false)`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to cancel the previous queued animation:

```
$(_element).find(".hide-message").on("click", function () {
    $(_element).stop(true, false).slideUp();
    _scope.successMessage = "";
});
```

Comment: It works in this way! Thanks so much! I will accept your answer later.